# ¿Cómo obtener un atributo de un nodo duplicado en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, xml

Buen día, estoy buscando extraer el siguiente nodo (CFDI + "Impuestos") a través de XDocument

```
<cfdi:Impuestos TotalImpuestosTrasladados="0.00">
    <cfdi:Traslados>
        <cfdi:Traslado Importe="0.00" TasaOCuota="0.000000" TipoFactor="Tasa" Impuesto="002"/>
    </cfdi:Traslados>
</cfdi:Impuestos>
```

Pero al momento de aplicar el método XDocument.Descendants(CFDI + "Impuestos") por razones obvias me trae también los nodos que son parte de CFDI:Conceptos (Impuestos descendientes de ese nodo) mas sin embargo pueden ver en el siguiente ejemplo que el nodo que quiero extraer no forma parte de ellos, al momento de buscar el atributo "TotalImpuestosTrasladados" no me es posible iterarlo ya que traigo información preliminar o coindicencias que no son directamente el nodo que busco, ¿qué otra solución es factible?, pensaba en algo como

```
var ax = XDocument.Parse(s)
                                 .Descendants(cfdi + "Comprobante")
                                 .GroupBy(x => x.Attribute("TotalImpuestosTrasladados").Value)
                                 .Where(g => g.Count() >= 0);
```

Pero este al momento de agrupar no me funciona, ¿alguna idea?, dejo ejemplo

```
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd">
    <cfdi:Emisor RegimenFiscal="XX" Nombre="XX" Rfc="XX"/>
    <cfdi:Receptor UsoCFDI="XX" Nombre="XX" Rfc="XX"/>
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto Descuento="XX" Importe="XX" ValorUnitario="XX" Descripcion="XX" Unidad="XX" ClaveUnidad="XX" Cantidad="XX" ClaveProdServ="XX">
            <cfdi:Impuestos>
                <cfdi:Traslados>
                    <cfdi:Traslado Importe="XX" TasaOCuota="XX" TipoFactor="XX" Impuesto="XX" Base="XX"/>
                </cfdi:Traslados>
            </cfdi:Impuestos>
        </cfdi:Concepto>
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Impuestos TotalImpuestosTrasladados="0.00">
        <cfdi:Traslados>
            <cfdi:Traslado Importe="0.00" TasaOCuota="0.000000" TipoFactor="Tasa" Impuesto="002"/>
        </cfdi:Traslados>
    </cfdi:Impuestos>
    <cfdi:Complemento>
        <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigitalv11.xsd" Version="XX" UUID="XX" FechaTimbrado="2022-05-17T17:21:33" RfcProvCertif="XX"/>
    </cfdi:Complemento>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

¡Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Una disculpa, ya pude realizarlo, dejo la respuesta si a alguien más le funciona, ¡saludos!.

```
xDocument.Root.Elements(cfdi + "Impuestos").ToList();
```